# Program a conditional based on aov() result

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I have a dataset with many factor levels. each factor has a left and right side and there are multiple entries for the factor/side combination. So it looks something like this:

```
Factor_type             Side       Value
factor1                 L           134
factor1                 R           112
factor2                 L           166
factor2                 R            72
```

I loop through each factor and perform an `aov()`analysis:

```
factorset <- c("factor1", "factor2", "factor3")
for(f in factorset){
  x <- mydata %>% filter(Factor_type == f) #creates a dataset of only desired factor

  a <- aov(data = x, formula = Value ~ Side)
```

I'd like to know how/if I can create a condition off of the aov analysis. essentially:

```
if(a == IS SIGNIFICANT){
    ggplot(x, aes(x = Side, y = Value)+geom_boxplot()
```

}

Comment: Have you try with summary ? if you use summary in an aov result one of the output is the p.value.

Answer (score 1):

Look at toy example. I'll generate some data

```
> x<-gl(5,5)
> y<-rnorm(25)
```

And run `aov`:

```
> a<-aov(y~x)
```

`summary` shows p-value in `Pr(>F)` column:

```
 > summary(a)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
 x            4  1.834  0.4584   0.519  0.722
 Residuals   20 17.651  0.8825
```

You can access it directly with:

```
> summary(a)[[1]][1,5]
[1] 0.722432
```

So, your piece of code is:

```
if(summary(a)[[1]][1,5]<0.05){
    ggplot(x, aes(x = Side, y = Value)+geom_boxplot()
}
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation. I don't know why I didn't think of the output as a table.